# How to create a scrollbar for my JTextArea using JScrollPane?

Tags: java, jscrollpane, scrollpane

The program compiles properly, but the scroll pane for the text area is not created. I really don't know why this is happening. I defined JscrollPane and even implemented it with scrollPane = new JScrollPane

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
public class GuiProject5 extends JFrame
{
private static final int WIDTH = 400;
private static final int HEIGHT = 300;
private JPanel lowerPanel;
private JLabel widthL, areaL;
private JTextArea areaTA;
private JTextArea ta;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private JTextField lengthTF;
private JCheckBox gergsC;
private JButton exitB;

//Button handlers:
private ExitButtonHandler ebHandler;

public GuiProject5()
{

    areaL = new JLabel("Label: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);

    lengthTF = new JTextField("TextField");

    lowerPanel = new JPanel();

    areaTA = new JTextArea("TextArea", 6, 8);

    ta = new JTextArea("stuff", 6, 8);

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

    gergsC = new JCheckBox("Checkbox");

    //Specify handlers for each button and add (register)     ActionListeners to each button.

    exitB = new JButton("Button");
    ebHandler = new ExitButtonHandler();
    exitB.addActionListener(ebHandler);

    setTitle("My Gui in java");
    Container pane = getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));

    //Add things to the pane in the order you want them to appear (left to right, top to bottom)

    pane.add(exitB);
    pane.add(lengthTF);
    pane.add(lowerPanel);
    ta = new JTextArea("Stuff", 6, 8);
    ta.setLineWrap(true);
    ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    lowerPanel.add(new JScrollPane(scrollPane));
    pane.add(new JScrolscrollpane);
    pane.add(gergsC);
    pane.add(areaL);



    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}


public class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    GuiProject5 rectObj = new GuiProject5();
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure this program compiles??? `pane.add(new JScrolscrollpane);
` Anyway, you have to add the text ares to the scroll pane before adding the scroll pane to `pane`

Comment: @A. Wabbi How do I add text area to the scroll pane?

Comment: `scrollpane.add(ta);`

Answer (score 0):

you should initialize `JScrollPane` like

```
jsp=new JScrollPane(textAreaObj);
```

and add it to the panel.

```
JScrollPane
```

is a container class. you should define the component on which you want scrollbars in `JScrollPane() constructor`
and add that jsp object in your layout

Comment: I tried what you said with the jsp = new JScrollPane(textArea Obj), but it still won't work for me.

private JTextArea textAreaObj;
jsp=new JScrollPane(textAreaObj);
pane.add(jsp);
pane.add(new JScrollPane(scrollPane));

Comment: why did you add pane.add(new JScrollPane(scrollPane));